# a person who behaves in an overly familiar way

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, adjectives

What do you call a person who behaves in an overly familiar way, taking too many liberties, saying things that only someone with a closer relationship with  you would normally say?

Comment: There's "glad-hander" -- one who, like a politician, greets everyone with a (possibly figurative) handshake and a smile, but is not especially sincere in doing so.

Comment: I call 'em creepy!

Comment: Perhaps ***clingy***?

Comment: Also, I would say that this is sometimes the case for people with autism. What I imply is that don't put real people under whatever term you find for that since the reasons of such behavior might be well different.

Answer (score 15):

I would say this person is '***forward***', from Webster:

> Lacking modesty or reserve.  Brash, poorly disciplined children are
>   often distressingly ***forward***.

Answer (score 11):

They are being ***over-familiar*** - *Too familiar. Inappropriately or unduly intimate or informal* (OED).

OR,

***Impertinent*** - (Of persons, their actions, etc.) *Meddling with what is beyond one's province; intrusive, presumptuous; behaving without proper respect or deference to superiors or strangers; insolent or saucy in speech or behaviour* (OED).

OR (just plain),

***Rude*** - Unmannerly, uncivil, impolite; offensively or deliberately discourteous.(OED)

Comment: Have a plus one for *Over-familiar*. *Impertinent* is interesting, the definition seems at first glance to meet the terms of the question, but the behaviour seems to come from a place of mischief or mere disrespect without the outwardly deceptive nature of the behaviour described in the question. What i took from the Question was behaviour  which would lead a third party to think the relationship was other than it was, which is the bit that makes it creepy.

Comment: @Spagirl - More context would be helpful.  'Impertinent' works for me in the context of someone you don't know asking questions whose answers are none of their business. 'Rude' is a simpler alternative!

Comment: Hmmm, I was going to disagree on the basis that the original proposition hadn't been someone asking questions whose answer was none of their business, but was about 'behav[ing] in an overly familiar way, taking too many liberties, saying things that only someone with a closer relationship with you would normally say'. But i see TFD http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Taking+Liberties has 'behave impertinently' as a meaning of 'take liberties', so perhaps my view was coloured by Rhetorician's comment about creepiness.

Answer (score 10):

The word you want is [presumptuous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presumptuous): (link and defintion from Merriam-Webster)

> overstepping due bounds (as of propriety or courtesy) : taking liberties

The word shares a root with *presume*, suggesting a person who presumes to know things better or to speak to people as they though were more familiar.  As an example:

> It was very presumptuous of Bob to ask Alice about the details of her vacation plans.

Comment: To me, presumptuous simply implies the person is quick to assume things. This seems a bit off topic to be honest. `

Comment: @oMiKeY Are you basing that on the fact that the word has "assume" as it's base? Also, can you post a link to that definition of **presumptuous**? I cannot find one but would be interested to see one.

Comment: The word presumptuous has the word "presume" at its base, not assume. But yes, it is the same idea. For a more descriptive explanation of both words, please see this link: http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000304.htm

Answer (score 5):

**Forward**

> confident and honest in a way that ignores the usual social rules and might seem rude ([Cambridge Dictionary adjective](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forward))

and

> too bold or free in manners; pushing; presumptuous ([Your Dictionary #5](http://www.yourdictionary.com/forward))

Comment: better definitions than the current top answer!

Answer (score 1):

Presumptuous - (of a person or their behavior) failing to observe the limits of what is permitted or appropriate.
"I hope I won't be considered presumptuous if I offer some advice"

Answer (score 0):

pert - boldly forward in speech or behavior; impertinent;

impertinent - intrusive or presumptuous,; brash, inappropriate

Comment: Please cite your sources.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, smitten or love-struck could fit.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.